# Mixing 0 with negative when removing indices in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if anyone could offer me an explanation as to why putting a -0 in place of a column or row indice removes all columns or rows.

Suppose I had

```
 mat<-matrix(1:9,3,3)
```

doing

```
mat[-0,]
```

produces

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]
```

similarly

```
    mat[-0,] 

[1,]
[2,]
[3,]
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Suppose I had something that could occasionally produce a 0 in the indices above, is there a way to avoid this behaviour other than using an if loop?

Comment: wrap your indices in `pmax`. This will cap it at whatever minimum value you want

Comment: See [the language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing) section 3.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` is not relevant, it's the index `0` that is. The index range for your `3x3` matrix is `rows: 1..3, columns: 1..3`.

When you try to access the row with index `0` (`mat[0,]`), you do (as pointed out my Roland below, thanks!) get a matrix with zero rows (and 3 columns). In the same way do `mat[,0]` yield a matrix with zero columns and 3 rows (i.e.; empty).

> A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x[0] is an
>   empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative
>   indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

Taken from [the language specs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing) (3.4.1) as pointed out by Roland in the comments to your question above.

```
mat<-matrix(1:9,3,3)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]   <-- mat[0,] there exists no data here
[1,]    1    4    7   <-- mat[1,] yields this row
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

dim(mat[0,])
[1] 0 3
```

Hence, you should make sure, as always, that your indices are not out of bounds (usually too large): the `0` index here can be considered somewhat out of bounds unless you intentionally want to *print* the column or row "titles", e.g.

```
print(mat[0,])
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
```

Comment: "mat[0,] yields this row" is not correct. It yields a matrix with zero rows.

Comment: Your edit shows clearly, that it is a matrix with 0 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: @Roland ah of course, you are right! So a better description would be that it *prints* the column title row?

Comment: Well, if you `print` it (implicitly). If you assign it, it is a 0-row matrix.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your feedback, I was too quick on this one.